# Confusing comment vote rate-limiting dialog

Tags: feature-request, comments, rate-limiting

The current comment vote rate-limiting dialog says:
[image]

This is confusing, since the rate limitation is **not** sliding, as the comment text implies. This can be seen by:

1. Voting on a comment
2. Waiting 4 seconds
3. Trying to vote on another comment, and watching the dialog pop up
4. 1 second later, trying to vote again on the same question

The second vote will go through, even though the dialog seems to say otherwise.

---

My proposed text for the box (from a comment):

> You may only vote on a comment every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Well, when your comment vote was rejected, the time was still ticking. Since that vote did not count, you didn't vote, hence you can vote a second later (after a total of at least 5 second since the last allowed comment vote).

This is just as described in the dialog and (in first instance) totally clear to me.

**Second thoughts**

Well, your comment proposing an adjustment to the text involving voting makes me clear this is indeed a little ambiguous.

The problem lies in the word `submit`, which gives some room for interpretation. The actual submission is done in the database and the system allowed only one every 5 seconds.

From the *point from the user* the submission is done on the moment of clicking the button, so there is the ambiguity.

I agree on your proposal and think this small adjusted would make it definitely clearer.

Comment: Although I thank you for accepting the answer, it might be better if you wait until someone from the development team catches this request and solve it.